# is there any real-valued function with following property

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convex-analysis, convex-geometry, orlicz-spaces

suppose we have a convex continuous function from$\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R^+}$
$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R^+}$ such that
$f(-x)=f(x),lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0 \text{ and } lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\infty$ and 
define $f_{1}(x)$=$e^{(\frac{-1}{x^2})}f(x)$
My question is can we define $f(x)$ such that
$f_1(x) =$
$\begin{cases}
      0 & :x\in[-k,k],\text{where}\hspace{0.2cm} k\in \mathbb{R}\\
      \text{it will increase } & : x\in(-\infty,-k)\cup(k,\infty)
    \end{cases} $

I hope I have written my question so that people can understand what I want to say, if there is any mistake please let me know.All I want is a function which is zero in a closed interval and then it increases and the final plot is like convex function,if I keep on changing the value of $k$ it should be zero in all those $[-k,k]$ for every $k\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: $f(x)=\max(x^2-k^2,0)$ should do.

Comment: But i think it is not satisfying the property $lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0$

Comment: It does. For $x\in(0,k)$ we have $f(x)=0$ and therefore $f(x)/x=0$. Then that limit is also zero.

Comment: Thank you so much, but actually, I made some mistakes in the question which I have updated it can you tell now.

Comment: No,I want $f_1$ should take value $0$ in $[-k,k]$ and then increase in $(-\infty,k)\cup(k,\infty)$

Answer (score 0):

what's wrong with:

$f(x)=0, -k\leq x\leq k\\
f(x)=x^2-k^2,(x>k\lor x<-k)$

it is continuous at $k,-k$, it convex and the limits exist at $0,\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Such a function cannot exist, unless it is identically $=0$. To see this, assume  $f_1$ is increasing on $(-\infty, -k)$ and not $=0$. Since $f$ is continuous, so is $f_1$, and this means that $f_1(x) \le 0 $ for $x<-k$, and, if not identically $0$, $f_1(x) < 0$ for some $x< -k$.

Since both $f$ and $e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ are non negative this is a contradiction.